# Change msg classes displaying form region (VS2010, Outlook Addin)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

Is it possible to change the answer to this once the region has been created?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you will have to re-register a new form region if you have any.

```
reg.Create(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\FormRegions"))
```

for an example.